# Does ASP.NET MVC 4 application have to be in the root folder of a site on IIS 8?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4

iI have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application based on the VS 2012 Basic template. Using VS 2012, I can deploy the app into a root of an IIS server, such as c:\inetpub\wwwroot. Then, I can go to [http://]mymachine/ and see the app.

But, if I try to move the app to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test, an attempt to access [http://]mymachine/Test results in "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."

I tried to move the folder both manually, and also by deploying to that folder from VS 2012, but there was no difference. I tried to move the web.config file into c:\inetpub\wwwroot while leaving the rest of the app under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test, but that also doesn't work. I have to move global.asax, global.asax.cs and the bin folder into the site root, but then the whole app is again in the root folder, which is not what I wanted.

Does anyone know whether what I'm trying to do is possible? Thanks.

PS.: Sorry about the link formatting - I used the square brackets around [http://] to prevent stackoverflow from treating the example URIs as links.

Comment: (FWIW: I usually use `http://link:of/textual?importance=only`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the sub-folder has been converted (or created) as an application in IIS. Load the IIS manager and locate the folder under the website node in the tree, right-click and select convert to application. If it's not listed, use the add application option.

Keep in mind that the child application will inherit web.config settings from it's parent by default (among other things). More information can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and makes it clearer to me what the solution would look like in my case.